# I can't test the context menu from ag-grid-angular

Tags: testing, ag-grid-angular

Hi All I have been trying to test one custom action from the aggrid context menu, I can dispatch an event from the app and it will give the context menu correctly for the cell. But for some reason on the testing api the contextMenuFactory is always null.

Any idea why? I am using aggrid 27.
Is the contextMenu simply not available while testing or am I missing something?

Let me know if you need a sample app. I have the feeling this is not available for testing (I could not find anything online) but if it is I can try to create a sample.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, it turns out that you need to include the license. after that the context was available.

for more context:
https://github.com/ag-grid/ag-grid-enterprise/issues/190